Пытаюсь востановить dump из persistentVolumeClaim в k8s, для создания dump использую backupSchedules

apiVersion: mysql.oracle.com/v2 kind: InnoDBCluster metadata: name: recovery-cluster spec: secretName: mycluster-cluster-secret tlsUseSelfSigned: true instances: 3 router: instances: 1 initDB: dump: storage: persistentVolumeClaim: path: /tmp/mycluster-mygreatschedule241206001502
Использую такой манифест для создания нового кластера с помощью бекапа, но они не запускаются, подскажите пожалуйста, что делаю не так???? Документации по данному вопросу очень мало
